# Finding k-Nearest-Neighbor in R with knn() from class package

Tags: r, statistics, classification, data-mining

This is home work.

I have a 2 matrices, 1 for training and 1 for test. 
The data has two columns of data which shall be used for classification and a third column with the known class. Both matrices has the third column.

```
    [1] [2] [3]
[1] 6.4 0.32 2
[2] 4.8 0.34 0
[3] 4.9 0.25 2
[4] 7.2 0.32 1
```

where the intergers are the classes (from 0-2).

The dimension for my datasets are 100 3 for the training set and 38 3 for the testing set.

I have tried to use the knn() function of the class lbrary.

knn uses the follwing arguments: (train, test, cl, k = 1, l = 0, prob = FALSE, use.all = TRUE)

I have tried to use my data sets directly, but then i get the error: "'train' and 'class' have different lengths"

I have tried a few thing, but I am stuck after some hours now. At the moment I have this code in my editor:

```
cl <- t(factor(c(rep("0",1), rep("1",1), rep("2",1))))
k <- knn(train, test, cl)
```

but it does not work. Can someone help me?

I want to find run the function with 3 different k-values, and find the accuracy of each. After that I will be 5-fold cross validating the best k.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276388/knn-in-r-train-and-class-have-different-lengths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation states `cl` is the `factor of true classifications of the training set` i.e. your `y` variable (the third column of your training set).

This means that the function should be as follows:

```
cl <- factor(c(2,0,2,1)) #or alternatively factor(train[,3])
k <- knn(train[,c(1,2)], test[,c(1,2)], cl)
```

As you can see in both training and test sets the `y` variable (the column with the classes) is not included in the test and training sets. The column is only included as a factor in the `cl` argument.

The error you received is because the number of rows of the training set is not equal to the length of the factor in which case it only had 3 elements (which is because you thought you only needed to specify the levels of the factor there).