# Error in knn 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor, knn

I'm trying to use the knn function (from the class package) on my dataset. It has 5 columns of features, and the 6th is what I want to be able to predict. I'm doing a 70/30 split.

Here's my code:

```
> ind <- createDataPartition(CSD$Caesarian, p=0.70, list=FALSE)
> csd_train <- CSD[ ind,]
> csd_test <- CSD[-ind,]
> c1 <- CSD[1:6,-c(1,2,3,4,5)]
> knn(train, test, c1, k=2, prob=TRUE)
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
Error in knn(train, test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

I looked at other threads and trying their suggested solutions ([KNN in R: 'train and class have different lengths'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276388/knn-in-r-train-and-class-have-different-lengths))

and tried the following, but I'm still getting errors

```
> c1 = as.factor(c1)
> dim(csd_train)
[1] 57  6
> dim(csd_test)
[1] 23  6
> length(c1)
[1] 6
> knn(train, test, c1, k=2, prob=TRUE)
Error in knn(train, test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

I also tried this, and still getting an error.

```
> c1 = as.factor(CSD[['Caesarian']])
> knn(train, test, c1, k=2, prob=TRUE)
Error in knn(train, test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

I'm lost as to how to fix this.

Here's a sample of my data if that helps:

```
> dput(head(CSD))
structure(list(Age = c(22L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 22L, 26L), Delivery.NO = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Delivery.NO.1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L
), BP = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L), Heart.Problem = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Caesarian = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Age", 
"Delivery.NO", "Delivery.NO.1", "BP", "Heart.Problem", "Caesarian"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

***EDIT***
I did

```
c1 <- csd_train[, 6]
```

and the length(c1) is now 57, which is good. However, when I run the knn line, I'm now getting this new error:

```
Error in knn(csd_train, csd_test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) : NA/NaN/Inf in `foreign function call (arg 6) In addition: Warning messages: 1: In` `knn(csd_train, csd_test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion 2:` `In knn(csd_train, csd_test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion`
```

All of my predictor  variables are numeric, and there are no missing values.

Comment: Can you provide an reproducible example of your error?

Comment: What are you doing in line 4 (`> c1 <- CSD[1:6,-c(1,2,3,4,5)]`?

Comment: I want the c1 to be just the last column - line four includes cols 1-6 but excludes cols 1-5, leaving only column 6.

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by "reproducible example"?

Comment: Take some data which are available for all and reproduce your error with this data. For example, I got your error using the `iris` data.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer.

Here is a working example using the `iris` dataset. You have to leave out the target variable in your train and test set. Pass the target variable for your train set to the argument `cl` within the `knn` call. Then it should work. 
In this example the target variable is in column 5.

The error occurs when the length of `cl` is not equal to the number of rows in your test set.

```
library(class)
library(caret)

dat<-iris

ind <- createDataPartition(dat$Species, p=0.70, list=FALSE)
dat_train <- dat[ ind,-5]         #leave your target variable out 
dat_test <- dat[-ind,-5]          #leave your target variable out
cl<-dat[ind,5]                    #your target variable for the train set
knn(dat_train, dat_test, cl, k=2, prob=TRUE)
```

*edit

I found the error in your code. If your data look like this:

```
> dim(csd_train)
 [1] 57  6
> dim(csd_test)
 [1] 23  6
> length(c1)
 [1] 6
```

it cannot work since the length of c1 (6) does not match with the number of rows of csd_train (57).

**Another edit:

Try exactly this:

```
ind <- createDataPartition(CSD$Caesarian, p=0.70, list=FALSE)
csd_train <- CSD[ ind,-6]
csd_test <- CSD[-ind,-6]
c1 <- CSD[ ind,6]
knn(csd_train , csd_test, c1, k=2, prob=TRUE)
```

Comment: Okay, hmm. So I will try `c1 <- csd_train[6]` which should (if I understand correctly) give me the target variable for the training set of length 57.

Comment: If your target variable is in the 6th column of  `csd_train` then it would be `c1 <- csd_train[ ,6]`.

Comment: I did `c1 <- csd_train[, 6]` and the `length(c1)` is now 57, which is good. However, when I run the knn line, I'm now getting this new error: `Error in knn(csd_train, csd_test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(csd_train, csd_test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(csd_train, csd_test, c1, k = 2, prob = TRUE) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Are all your predictor variables numeric? Do they contain missing values?

Comment: I think here is a solution for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874038/error-with-knn-function

Comment: Yes, all my variables are numeric and there are no missing values.